# Wiring an induction cooktop

Tags: wiring

I want to install a new Ge induction cooktop & have an existing 4 wire line. If the cooktop only requires a black, red & bare ground, is the white still attached in the panel if it’s capped off and not used at the cooktop junction?

Comment: No reason to disconnect the neutral in the panel. Just cap it in the box, if it is not needed. This cooktop only requires 240 V?

Comment: Yes cooktop only requires 240. 
The wiring was disconnected in the panel. Is there any need to re-attach the white then? 
Also, a note in the instructions warns about attaching copper from cooktop wiring to aluminum ( from panel wiring appears to be aluminum ). Special wire nuts,etc?

Comment: Aluminum wire must have connectors Listed for Aluminum and Listed for the size of the wires used. Regular wirenuts are not Listed for aluminum. If #10 or smaller wire Alumiconn https://kinginnovation.com/products/39/2-port-alumiconn may work, or Polaris IT-4 will also work with larger wire.

Comment: So no need for the white wire to be hooked in panel or at cooktop junction? It’s not used at all?

Comment: If the cable has a ground as well as an insulated white and your device only needs 240 V, then the white can stay disconnected in the panel, if it is currently disconnected. Does your new appliance have a white wire in its cable?

Comment: No. No white on the appliance wire. 
Thanks. I’m starting to get a clearer understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Jim.  Just cap the white wire in the box.  You are fortunate to have a 4 wire feed, in most cases here people have the opposite problem:  "Requiring a 4 wire feed for a new cooktop but only having 2 hots and a ground".

Comment: Or worse, "2 hots and a neutral, and needing ground".

Comment: @Harper  if a ground is needed a new one can be pulled so that’s not worse than 2 Hots and a ground, no way around that one.

Comment: @ed good point...